# Does the download speed account for intra-network connections?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking

My current internet plan is 500 mbps for download and 40 mbps for upload. My previous plan was 50 download and 50 upload. In my previous space, the wireless connection between devices would frequently drop.

Since my current plan has higher bandwidth for download, would there be less interference and would there be a more stable connection between my devices?

In other words, does the download bandwidth account for the bandwidth needed for wireless connections between my devices within the network (i.e., between my devices and the router), or does it only account for the bandwidth of information flowing from the Internet/ISP through my router (and then to my devices)?

Answer (score 2):

The plan only affects the connection between the ISP and your home (modem). Your local network is in fact fully local and its speed and reliability is only determined by the hardware you're using. (And by neighbor interference, since Wi-Fi is a radio link...)

Comment: Thank you. How can I improve the performance of my local network? What's the metric I should be looking for? I would really like to avoid network instability between my devices (such as wireless computers and printers)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer - just a suggestion.

If you have a smartphone, get a wifi analyser application.  Then walk around the house checking the signal.  Don't take the first reading - wait at least 20 to 30s for a proper reading.  It will also tell you what the neighbouring signals are.  Maybe just changing channels will solve your problem.  Everyone loves channel 1 - just try a different channel.

PCs are good up to -50dB.  Phones can survive on a -70dB signal.  Try it with doors open and doors closed.  This will tell you the dead spots in your house and where you can or cannot get a wifi signal.

In my house there are some dead areas because wire mesh was nailed to the walls when the plasterer did the rendering.  Causes a Faraday cage type effect.

**Edit** Channels

WiFi uses a range of frequencies.  At 2.4GHz, this is divided into 11 sub ranges.  Each sub-range is called a channel.  At 5GHz, it is divided into 45 channels.

If you do a google search for ***Router Channels***, the first few hits explain how to change it etc.  They explain it better than I ever could.

Comment: Thank you. Could you elaborate what you mean more by changing channels?

Comment: By increasing the bandwidth of the local network, would there theoretically be less interference since each device could operate on its own frequency band?